# XSD sequence with special condition at the end

Tags: xml, xsd

I am trying to find the best way to implement following structure for XML file using XSD scheme:

```
<Vertice></Vertice>
<Edge></Edge>
...any number of Vertices and Edges between...
<Vertice></Vertice>
<Edge></Edge>
```

So it must always contain Start-Vertice, End-Vertice and one Edge between them, but optionally it may contain as many Vertices in the middle as needed, each of them surrounded by Edges (XML will be created later by JAXB based on this scheme). I was trying to use something like this, but it doesn't compile. Is there any proper way to implement it?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <!-- declaration -->
    <xs:complexType name="graphType">
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:element name="vertice" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="edge" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="vertice" type="xs:string"/>       <!-- this line is not working -->
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- printing -->
    <xs:element name="Graph" type="graphType"/>

</xs:schema>
```

I have also figured out something like this, but it's not allowed to use the same name once again, hence I would need to change the name of last vertice. But maybe there is a way to find workaround for this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <!-- declaration -->
    <xs:complexType name="graphType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="2" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="vertice" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="edge" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="vertice-end" type="xs:string"/>  
            <!-- is there a workaround to repeat the name "vertice" for this element? -->
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- printing -->
    <xs:element name="Graph" type="graphType"/>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply do it the other way, i.e consider your model must begin with a `vertice`, and then is a sequence of `edge`+`vertice` (it is the same, isn't it?). This way you are ensured that you always end on a `vertice` element.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

    <!-- declaration -->
    <xs:complexType name="graphType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="vertice" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:element name="edge" type="xs:string"/>
                <xs:element name="vertice" type="xs:string"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- printing -->
    <xs:element name="Graph" type="graphType"/>

</xs:schema>
```

You were likely to be facing a problem called *Unique Particle Attribution*, you can read more here https://www.w3.org/wiki/UniqueParticleAttribution (or make your own search).

Comment: Great, thanks a lot - of course it fits the result I needed. However I can't see a reason why it didn't compile when vertice element was added after the sequence and it did when it was before the sequence - some magic of XSD I guess that I need to remember:) Or is there any simple explanation of it?

Comment: Actually one more problem has just appeared - Next thing was to generate Java classes using XJC, but it gives me an error `[ERROR] Element "vertice" shows up in more than one properties`. If it's relevant, my XJC version is `xjc 2.2.8-b130911.1802`. Is there any way to apply workaround for it?

Comment: Hi - regarding your first comment, please have a look at the link I provided at the end of the answer, it is the explanation why you are not allowed to define your content like you did. Regarding you second comment, I believe your should ask a new question.